# Why does the Path Breadcrumb module change URLs?

Tags: 7, uri, i18n-l10n

I have a multilanguage site. I had a link to `node/drupal_get_path_alias('node/15')` and works perfectly identifying the language of the site, so it gets the correct path ("products" for english, "productos" for spanish). I have installed [Path Breadcrumb](https://www.drupal.org/project/path_breadcrumbs), tried to configure, and to my surprise, the link which previously worked is rewritten to the incorrect language, instead of "/productos" is "/products". **The link is in the main HTML, in the `preprocess_page`**. Why does Path Breadcrumb rewrites a path instead of just creating the breadcrumb? I uninstall the module and all works as intended again.

Answer (score 0):

It was completely my fault. Path Breadcrumb works perfectly. The problem is that I had a path alias which instead of being English, it was All languages, and so the module didn't know what link to choose. I hadn't noticed the error before installing the module, and somehow the module installation made the error to be detectable.